# Switching to newly created site from bench not working

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I am learning frappe framework following the tutorial on the website.

I created a new site as well as an app, after thatinstalled the new app on the newly created site, the used the command `$ bench use library` but i am unable to load the new site "library". but when i go to `localhost:8080` i get ERPNext site. i am using Virtual Image.

I have already tried restarting  `bench`
the `currentsite.txt` file contains "library"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using production setup (gunicorn/nginx) or developer setup (bench start)?

If you are developing, use bench start instead of production setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your site in your browser using the site name, you have to add it to `/etc/hosts` first.

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 library
```

Now, you can access your site at http://library:8000 in your browser.

The tutorial is now updated and explains these steps in detail:
https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/tutorial/create-a-site#access-site-in-your-browser